rank decomposition with rank deficient matrix
Consider a matrix $X=[X_1, X_2, X_3]$ where $X_1$ has full column rank, $X_2$ is either full rank, rank deficient or zero matrix, and $X_3=0$. If $X_1 a \neq X_2 b$ holds for $a \neq 0$ and $b \neq 0$, does $rank[X] = rank[X_1] + rank[X_2]$ hold regardless of whether $X_2$ has full rank or not?

The answer is no. As a simple counterexample, take
$$
X_1 = I_2, \quad X_2 = 2I_2, \quad X_3 = \pmatrix{0\0}.
$$
$I_2$ denotes the $2 \times 2$ identity matrix. We have $\text{rank}(X) = \text{rank}(X_1) = \text{rank}(X_2) = 2$.
